# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I'm getting a strange error in a Laravel project I'm working on.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near '='. [20018] (severity 15) [(null)] (SQL: update [plan_part] set [is_corrosion_protection_required] = 0, [modified_date] = 2018-01-24 11:47:03 where [plan_part_id] = 131996)

It is happening on my test server, but locally it is working. The test server is running PHP 7.1.10 and the localhost is WAMP running 7.0.10.

I don't understand why this is causing an error. The syntax appears to be correct. I'm just using Laravel's eloquent model to save to the database, which I'm pretty sure is just a PHP PDO bound parameter statement.

Strangely, I am able to save on the test server if I tweak a different property other than `is_corrosion_protection_required`. That property is a `bit` property in the DB. I tried changing it to use true/false, 1/0, '1'/'0' and 'yes'/'no', but it didn't fix anything.

I am getting the same problem on another bit field, so I think it has to do with that, but I have no idea what I need to do or where to go from here.

Hoping someone can provide some clues as to what else I can try or what I need to do to get this working on both localhost and the test server.

I don't think the more updated 7.1 version is a major problem, but I don't know much about server administration.

Comment: Just an idea, buy it could be the date string messing with you ..  Are you using the same database server?  Possibly strict queries is turned on with one and not the other? This doesn't seem like a PHP issue.

Comment: I have moved mysuggested solution to the comments. Please see this solution: I would suggest that Quantastical try  a hotfix on the server or a new version of the OLE provider. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2465092/fix-sqlstate-hy000-error-occurs-when-you-use-microsoft-ole-db-provider

 I have had similar issues that I solved by using a different data provider.

Comment: @Zak Thanks for your comment. I also thought it could be date related as we had some issues with date stuff in the past. I tried modifying the date format in Eloquent's SqlGrammar file to no avail. I thought it was more related to bit because I was able to save other, varchar/integer-based properties which I presumed would include the modified_date value as well. Both environments are connecting to the same database.

Comment: I was able to confirm that it does not have to do with the date field as the error persists even when I include `public $timestamps = false` in the Eloquent model. The new query doesn't have any date fields and it still bombs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of research, I was able to come to the conclusion that our problem was not with the original query that is outlined in the error message.

There were triggers associated with the table in question and those triggers were potentially the root cause of the problem. I can't say for certain what exactly was throwing the error, but our DBA reviewed the triggers and disabled them causing everything to work again.

Thanks for all the comments and assistance in reviewing my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen from server side not from your project, You need to make sure you are complete and success install `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` modules on server.

When you run these command `pecl install pdo_sqlsrv` and `pecl install sqlsrv`, make sure the process done successful, and you see this message at end of process:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.
```

Answer (score -2):

This problem is caused by charset!

```
execute [ iconv(); ]
```